# Error installing tensor flow in R studio

Tags: r, tensorflow

This is how I tried installing tensorflow using R studio.

```
install.packages("tensorflow")
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow()
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
>> library(tensorflow)
>> install_tensorflow()
```

Preparing for installation (updating pip if necessary)
E:\python\python.exe: No module named pip
Error: Error 1 occurred updating pip
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"E:\python\python.exe" -m pip install --upgrade pip' had status 1

Has anyone got any idea on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Check , if python is installed on your machine. If not, install it and try to install tensorflow again

Comment: Hi! Actually Python is installed on my laptop. I tried installing tensorflow using pip for python and it did get installed. The error occurs only when I try to install tenserflow function using Rstudio. Any help would be big!
Been struck with this for a long time now..